# DataSet Expression Column Re-Evaluation

Tags: c#, .net, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a strongly typed data set that contains a `readonly` column calculated by its expression property. The calculated column is a `totalAmountDue` and the expression is `( totalAmountBilledColumn - totalAmountPaidColumn )`.  The problem is I can't get the calculated column to re-evaluate when either of the two calculating columns are changed.

Does anyone know how to force the data set to re-evaluate columns with expressions?

Thanks.

Comment: If you try checking the value of the column with debugger it will be correct. It just don't fire ColumnChanged-like events. I do not know how to force a DataTable to send such an event for a computed read-only column. But if you invalidate the data-bound control it'll read the correct value.

Comment: Yes I found that an AcceptChanges() call followed by a  BeginEdit() <editingcode> EndEdit() will cause the column to have the right value.  I just find it strange that there are no events or anything that let you know when the column is being evaluated.  Thanks for y our help.

Answer (score 3):

Just came across this. Funny thing about expressions is that they don't evaluate until row is added to table. Once a row is added to table, It will work. Here is an example.

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("debit", typeof (double)).DefaultValue = 0;
        table.Columns.Add("credit", typeof(double)).DefaultValue = 0;
        table.Columns.Add("net", typeof(double),"debit - credit");

        DataRow row = table.NewRow();

        Console.WriteLine("First: {0}",row["net"]); // won't work
        row["debit"] = 500;
        Console.WriteLine("Sec: {0}", row["net"]); // won't work
        row["credit"] = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Thr: {0}", row["net"]); // won't work

        table.Rows.Add(row);
        Console.WriteLine(row["net"]); // works
```